# Assign the cart delivery address to Guest User address

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have a requirement where I need to retain the delivery address of the CartModel to the Guest user when he login again in the same session.
But not able to save the address, as getting the modelSavingException.

customerAddresses is the list of AddressModel.

```
final CartModel cartModel = cartService.getSessionCart();
customerAddresses.add(cartModel.getDeliveryAddress());
currentCustomer.setSaveAddress(customerAddresses);
currentCustomer.setAddresses(customerAddresses);
modelService.save(currentCustomer);
```

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace of the exception? (Why are you getting the modelSaveException?)

Comment: It is resolved, so I have used OOTB defaultAddressService.cloneAddressForOwner to retain the values.

Comment: That's good to hear. You should probably post that as an answer instead of a comment, and accept it later. :)